# what is the value of $k?$ Is $p=k , p>k$ or $p <k?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

**Proposition 38.** Let $p(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial over a field $F$ of characteristic
$p$. Then there is a unique integer $k > 0$ and a unique irreducible separable polynomial
$p_{sep}(x) \in F[x]$ such that
$$p(x) = p_{sep}(x^{p^k}).$$

**My confusion** : what is the value of $k?$

Is  $p=k , p>k$ or $p <k?$

Im confused

**My thinking** : Take $p(x)= x^{p^k} -c$

If $k=p$ , then $p(x)=x^{p^p}-c \implies p(x)= x^{p^p}-t^{p^p}=(x-t)^{p^p}$

$p(x)$  is reducible

If $k >p$, then  $p(x)=x^{p^k}-c \implies p(x)= x^{p^k}-t^{p^p}=(x-t)^{p^k}$

$p(x)$ is reducible

If $k <p$, then  $p(x)=x^{p^k}-c \implies p(x)= x^{p^k}-t^{p^p}=(x-t)^{p^k}$

$p(x)$ is irreducible

Now  using the theorem **every irreducible polynomial over a finite field is separable**

Therefore if $k <p $,then  there exist a unique irreducible separable polynomial
$p_{sep}(x) \in F[x]$ such that
$$p(x) = p_{sep}(x^{p^k}).$$

Comment: Please don't use $p$ to denote the characteristic as well as the polynomial.

Comment: $k$ depends on $p$ (the polynomial). So you cannot compare $k$ and $p$ (the characteristic), in general.

Comment: As a hint, consider the fact that taking $p$-th powers is a homomorphism in characteristic $p$ (you have used this already in your thinking). For example, it follows easily that $k=0$ if $p$ (the polynomial) is separable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$, a prime.$\DeclareMathOperator{\sep}{sep}$

**Note.** If $F$ is a finite field, then every irreducible polynomial is separable. So, given any irreducible $f(x) \in F[x]$, the $k$ in question will be $0$ and $f_{\sep} = f$ itself.
(In particular, you cannot always take $k > 0$. I suppose that in your question, you wish to start with an irreducible inseparable polynomial to begin with.)

---

But in general, $k$ can take any value. Consider the field $F = \Bbb F_p(t)$.
Fix $k \geqslant 1$. Consider the polynomial $f(x) = x^{p^k} - t \in F[x]$. By Eisenstein, $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$.
Now, let $g(x) := x - t$. Then, note that $g(x)$ is irreducible. Moreover, considering the formal derivative shows that $g(x)$ is separable as well. Clearly, $$f(x) = g(x^{p^k}).$$
Thus, the above is the decomposition that you desired. (We have $f_{\sep} = g$.)

Since $k$ was arbitrary, we see that there is no comparison between $p$ and $k$ in general.

---

Note that the "unique $k > 0$ and unique $f_{\sep}(x) \in F[x]$" only means that they are unique once you have fixed $f(x)$. In other words, $k$ and $f_{\sep}$ both depend on $f$.